# Cerrar sesion y al apretar el boton regresar no me mande a paginas como si estuviera logueado

Tags: php, html5

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    include ("conexion.php");
    //ini_set('session.save_path',$_SERVER['session'].'/session');
    $nivel = $_SESSION["autentificado"];
    $nom = $_SESSION["nombre"];
    $ape = $_SESSION["apellido"];
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from usuarioss where correo = '$email'");
    $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Control de ventas</title>
```

Tengo esta linea de codigo, como vemos al empezar es codigo php para iniciar sesion despues de haberme logueado, mi problema es que cuando le doy cerrar sesion:

```
<div class="modal-body">Selecciona "SALIR" si estás listo para terminar sesión.</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php">Salir</a>
    </div>
```

Cierra la sesion, le doy al boton regresar en la barra del chrome y me regresa a una pagina como si estuviera logueado y no al login.

Comment: tu index.php es tu código que pusiste primero?

Comment: si es lo primero que tengo en mi archivo index

Comment: Haz condiciones `if(isset(!$_SESSION["autenticado"]))` que lo mande al login

Comment: Me ayudarias a mencionar donde poner esa condicion, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

En cada página se puede agregar condiciones como esta:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

     header('location: index.php');
}
```